# Is it possible for a Regular Expression to Lookahead OR Lookbehind?

Tags: regex

I'm struggling to create some kind of RegEx that can either look ahead or look behind.

Something ideal would be to match the **a** in both **ab** and **ba**, triggered by the presence of the **b**.

Obviously I could repeat the **a**, such as:

```
((?<=b)a)|a(?=b)
```

But can it be done without the repetition of the matching set?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` always one character, or substitutes for longer strings? Should `a` match in `bab`? What about `bba` or `abb`?

Comment: When asking about a regex, you should specify which kind; which language or library. Not all regex engines support the same features.

Comment: @acheong87 Yeah, they are substitutes for much longer strings, which ideally should be easy to change. Correct, `bab` should match.

Comment: Whoops, I meant PCRE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Disclaimer:** This answer is using the **PCRE** syntax/flavor. The syntax may differ from other flavors and some of them don't support it at all.

First of all, I will just warn you that you should just go with the following: `(?<=b)a|a(?=b)`. It's simple and easy to follow.

Now if you want to see another solution, I've come up with the following `a(?(?=b)|(?<=b.))`. So what does this mean ?

```
a               # match a
(?              # if
    (?=b)       # there is a "b" ahead
    |           # else
    (?<=b.)     # there is a "b" 2 steps behind
)               # end if
```

<kbd>[**Online demo**](http://regex101.com/r/uG9iM6)</kbd>

Comment: Just a heads up. The OP has clarified that `a` and `b` are stand-ins for longer strings. However, modifying your expression accordingly would result in a variable-length lookbehind, I believe.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/eP2bJ8 to match `all` before or after a b. It matches `allb`, `ball` but not `call`. This is really nice.

Comment: @acheong87 Well when I answered it, it wasn't clarified like that. I thought the OP wanted to know a different approach. I struggled a bit and this is the only pattern I could come up with. That's why I said in the beginning of the answer that it's way more easier and cleaner to use `(?<=b)a|a(?=b)`. As for the variable-length lookbehind, there is a not-well-known alternative: the `\K` escape sequence. It will "forget" everything that's matched before (except for the matching groups >= 1). See for example [the following demo](http://regex101.com/r/kZ3hX9). Of course, we can't use it here.

Comment: I know, and I know you answer a lot of the regex questions, so when OP clarified, I wasn't sure you'd get alerted, so I was just giving you a heads up. I was going to edit the `.` in your answer to reflect the clarification for you, but that's where I wasn't sure about variable-length lookbehinds, so I decided not to edit your answer and let you work it out. But in any case, it looks like OP is okay with a set length, _i.e._ `.{3}` as per his example, so everything's fine. I knew vaguely about `\K` but thought that was only supported in a limited set of languages like Perl, PHP, and .NET.

Comment: Regardless, I wouldn't have thought to use `\K` to get around that problem, so that's nice; thanks.

Comment: @HamZa I like the `\K`, but for some reason my dnGREP doesn't seem to support it. =/

Comment: @HamZa Do you know if it's possible to construct said regex without having to duplicate the `b`?

Comment: @CayetanoGonçalves is replacing `b` with `\1` for example ok ? What's your goal in the end ?

Answer (score 1):

The matching set seems the simplest and clearest approach to me.  That said, you could always build a lookahead-only regex and then apply it to both the target string and its reverse.